# TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer deprecated - Replacement

Tags: java, resteasy, deprecated

I see that TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer (org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.tjws.TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer) is deprecated. In the docs https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.1.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/server/tjws/TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer.html it says "See resteasy-undertow module." Is UndertowJaxrsServer a replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use any of the following:

- `UndertowJaxrsServer`
- `NettyJaxrsServer`
- `CdiNettyJaxrsServer`
- `VertxJaxrsServer`